# Inserting new row and updating values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

What I'm trying to do seems fairly simple at first, but its giving me a hard time. I have 3 Tables. Table A contains a list of Jobs. Table B contains a list of Actions. Table C contains the the intersection of those 2 tables, meaning that it contains a list of Jobs with associated Actions where the Actions are given an Action Order (the order in which the Actions execute). For example 1 Job can have 8 different actions which are ranked #1-8 and so on.

Here is where I'm at

```
Declare @T_variable TABLE(JobClassId int)
INSERT INTO @T_variable 
SELECT JobClassId
FROM CFG.JobClass 
WHERE jobClassDesc IN ('BD Staff Clerical','DOT Driver','DOT Frontline Supervisor and Asst Facility Managers','DOT Manager Ops','Driver Non DOT','Frontline Hourly','Frontline Supervisors and Asst Facility Managers','Manager Ops','Special Events','Special Events Flagger','Valet')

DECLARE @JobClassId1 int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT JobClassId
FROM @T_variable

OPEN db_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @JobClassId1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM CFG.ActionJobClass WHERE JobClass = @JobClassId1 ORDER BY ActionOrder ASC

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @JobClassId1
END

CLOSE db_cursor
```

This gives me a list of Actions that are ordered by their ActionOrder for each job.

What I want to do is insert a new Action for each Job into this table at a certain point (always after another specific Action) and when doing so, update the ActionOrder so that it works sequentially. For example, I want to insert a new Action for a job after another specified Action (Action 'C' for example).The current list for a Job would be: (TAKE NOTE: the numbers on the left hand side are the values for the Action Order column in Table C)

1. Action 'A'
2. Action 'B'
3. Action 'C'
4. Action 'D'
5. Action 'E'

After my insert of a new Action (Action 'F') into the spot right after Action 'C' the new list would be:

1. Action 'A'
2. Action 'B'
3. Action 'C'
4. Action 'F'
5. Action 'D'
6. Action 'E'

From what I gather I need to do the following:

1. Create new Action (Done, I've already added the new Action to the Action table)
2. Select Job List Id's (Done, I have them in the T-variable table)
3. Loop over Jobs
4. Select List of Actions for the Job that I'm currently on in the Job loop (Done kinda? I've shown that I can display them in the select statement within the loop)
5. Create index variable (Not sure if this is necessary, though possibly since I need to keep track of the Order Numbers)
6. Loop over the list of Actions for the Job
7. Insert my new Action into the list of Actions after designated Action.
8. Update following (previously existing) Actions to have +1 added to their Action Order #

I just don't know how to translate this into a SQL script. If it were C# it would be easy!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using cursors or "loops" for any of this. It's certainly possible to do this via set operations, using CTEs and ROW_NUMBER() to recalculate the number values.

Comment: That's the problem - you are applying procedural C# logic to a database. You don't need to do any looping at all.