# SQL update order after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where each element is given a order number (numbered 1-50).

I would like to insert a new item after a specified item (usually listed around the 6 or 7 mark) and then update each following element with the new appropriate order number.

For example, I want to insert the new element 'Zoo' after the element "Airport". Here is the list:

```
 - OrderNumber = 1, Name = "Bus Stop"
 - OrderNumber = 2, Name = "Dock"
 - OrderNumber = 3, Name = "Airport"
 - OrderNumber = 4, Name = "Ramp"
 - OrderNumber = 5, Name = "Pathway"
```

After insert of new element:

```
 - OrderNumber = 1, Name = "Bus Stop"
 - OrderNumber = 2, Name = "Dock"
 - OrderNumber = 3, Name = "Airport"
 - OrderNumber = 4, Name = "Zoo"
 - OrderNumber = 5, Name = "Ramp"
 - OrderNumber = 6, Name = "Pathway"
```

Notice the order numbers that are updated after inserting the new element "Zoo" in the specified location.

How do I get this to work in SQL?

**UPDATE:**
I'm using SQL Server Management Studio. And yes, this has to be in SQL. 
And to further clarify I asked a more specific and detailed question here that never really got answered: [Inserting new row and updating values in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775661/inserting-new-row-and-updating-values-in-sql)

Comment: Is there a particular flavor of SQL that you're using?

Comment: You should instead UPDATE first to make space then insert. Can you post any existing queries?

Comment: Do you have to do it in sql? might be easier to do it in whatever programming language you are using to call the sql...

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you know your new value is getting the order number of 4

```
update <table> set OrderNumber = OrderNumber + 1 where orderNumber >= 4
insert into <table> (ordernumber, Name) values (4, 'Zoo')
```

EDIT:
On second reading this doesn't really answer you question. What information do you know at the start? Just that 'Zoo' needs to go after 'Airport'?

If that is the case:

```
declare @to_insert varchar(30) = 'Zoo' 
declare @inserted_at varchar(30) = 'Airport'

declare @inserted_at_OrderNumber int

select @inserted_at_ordernumber = ordernumber 
from <table> 
where name = @inserted_at

insert into <table> (ordernumber,name) 
    values (@inserted_at_ordernumber, @to_insert)

update <table> 
set OrderNumber = OrderNumber + 1 
where orderNumber >= @inserted_at_ordernumber 
    and name <> @to_insert
```

If you let us know how you would like this to behave we can tailor it a bit better

Comment: To further clarify I asked a similar question in more detail earlier that never really got answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775661/inserting-new-row-and-updating-values-in-sql

Comment: I think you wanted strictly greater than in your queries and not greater than or equal. But I kind of didn't look really close so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Ah, I see. So we want to do this same thing across multiple codes. Allow me to ponder that. I'll see about giving you a better answer in that other question when I get a bit of sit down time! @shawnt00, I wanted to update the 4 as well, so the >= works. It does look a bit wonky, more self explanatory than inserted_at_ordernumber -1 would be :)

Comment: Nevermind what I said about that. But would it make more sense to do the update before the insert in the case case just as you had done earlier?

Comment: In your other answer, I assume the commenter assumed that since you didn't respond, you had disappeared (as many posters do) so it wasn't worth cooking up this enormous reponse if you never came back.

Comment: Nice, but there is "=" missing   st declare the scalar variable "@inserted_at".    declare @inserted_at varchar(50)  =' Airport'